# Redirect query string to non-query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for an `.htaccess` rule, which redirects:

```
http://abcde.com/?q=abc
```

Where `abc` can be any string to:

```
http://abcde.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```